# Sass/CSS Grid and same height/width

Tags: css, grid, dimensions, susy-compass

I have defined a grid with columns widths to fit my desired content.

Say, I then wish to place an element using the grid so I have it span 3 of the 9 columns for an approx width of 33.3%

I then wish that element to be the same height as it's width.

This is the point I always get stuck. If I use Compass Susy's columns() function it sets the height to 33.3% which is exactly what it is meant to do but obviously it's not what I want.

How do people work around this to get the desired outcome?

Kind regards,
Neil

Answer (score 0):

No need for JS. It's possible with a simple HTML and CSS Trick:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
<div class="item"><div class="content"></div></div>
<div class="item"><div class="content"></div></div>
<div class="item"><div class="content"></div></div>    
</div>
```

**Relevant CSS**

```
.container{
  position: absolute;
}

.item{
    height: 0;
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 33%;
}

.item .content{
   height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/opherv/hjVSM/

Try to resize to browser and see how it behaves.

The Idea is that you set the width/height ratio using the element's padding-bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Thnanks for your answer @OpherV but @rctneil didn't even mention JS.
He (like me) is looking for a Sass/Susy solution.

Is there any Sass mixin which sets the height of an element which has a dynamic width equal to it's width?